# SQLite divide each row by values of the same row from another table

Tags: python, sqlite

So how would one take each row in a table and divide each column value for that row by the corresponding value in another table

say i have a table_one

```
      A    B    C
0     12    20    12
```

and table_two

```
date        A    B    C
01/01/19    6    10   3  
02/01/19    12   5    6
```

and by dividing each cell in each row in table_two by the corresponding value in table_one to make the new table

```
date        A    B      C
01/01/19    0.5  0.5    0.25  
02/01/19    1    0.25   0.5
```

I thought about using an INNER JOIN like

```
"""INSERT INTO newtable( date, A, B, C) 
      SELECT t.date,
             t.A / s.A
             t.B / s.B
             t.C / s.C
      FROM table_two t
      INNER JOIN table_one s
      ON ;"""
```

But then I don't think this is correct as I don't know what I would put after the ON statement?

Comment: What determines which row in the second table corresponds to which row in the first table? If you know that it's a trivial join like you have. Just needs the ON part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the calculation to run directly across the rows (with the first element of the second table divided by the first element of the first table, ...) then you could give a number-id (that auto-increments for each row) column to each table and then join on that number-id.

This would call for recreating the table with this ID column, which would look like this at the top:

```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ...
```

You include a date on there as well. If you would like to perform the calculation on the date, it could work if the dates are unique.

For the first scenario, your INSERT statement would end like this:

```
  FROM table_two t
  INNER JOIN table_one s
  ON t.id = s.id;
```

If the scenario is the date-column join then it would just be:

```
  FROM table_two t
  INNER JOIN table_one s
  ON t.date = s.date;
```

And this is assuming your tables have columns like (id, date, A, B, C)

I hope that at least gives you some idea.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for the correct syntax and details about how sqlite works.

Answer (score 0):

> how would one take each row in a table and divide each column value
>   for that row by the corresponding value in another table?

Corresponding to what?
In the sample data you posted about `table_one` there is a `0` at the beginning of the row.
Does this mean that there is only 1 row in the table and it will always be just 1 row?
If the answer is *yes* then you need a `CROSS JOIN` between the tables which will join the only row of `table_one` to every row of `table_two`:

```
INSERT INTO newtable( date, A, B, C) 
SELECT t.date,
  t.A / s.A,
  t.B / s.B,
  t.C / s.C
FROM table_two t CROSS JOIN table_one s
```

If the answer is *no* then you need a to set a condition in the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO newtable( date, A, B, C) 
SELECT t.date,
  t.A / s.A,
  t.B / s.B,
  t.C / s.C
FROM table_two t INNER JOIN table_one s
ON s.somecolumn = t.othercolumn
```